# OpenMP C++ matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, openmp

I'd like to parallelize the following code. Especially these for loops, since it is the most expensive operation.

```
      for (i = 0; i < d1; i++)
         for (j = 0; j < d3; j++)
             for (k = 0; k < d2; k++)
             C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j];
```

It is the first time I tried  parallelizing code using OpenMP. I have tried several things but I always end up having a worse runtime than by using the serial version. 
It would be great if u could tell me if there is something wrong with the code or the pragmas...

```
      #include <omp.h>
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <stdlib.h>
      //#include <stdint.h>

      // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // allocate space for empty matrix A[row][col]
      // access to matrix elements possible with:
      // - A[row][col]
      // - A[0][row*col]


      float **alloc_mat(int row, int col)
      {
          float **A1, *A2;

          A1 = (float **)calloc(row, sizeof(float *));      // pointer on rows
          A2 = (float *)calloc(row*col, sizeof(float));    // all matrix elements

          //#pragma omp parallel for
          for (int i=0; i<row; i++)
              A1[i] = A2 + i*col;

          return A1;
      }

      // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // random initialisation of matrix with values [0..9]

      void init_mat(float **A, int row, int col)
      {   
          //#pragma omp parallel for
          for (int i = 0; i < row*col; i++)
              A[0][i] = (float)(rand() % 10);
      }

      // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // DEBUG FUNCTION: printout of all matrix elements

      void print_mat(float **A, int row, int col, char *tag)
      {
          int i, j;

          printf("Matrix %s:\n", tag);
          for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
          {
              //#pragma omp parallel for
              for (j=0; j<col; j++) 
                  printf("%6.1f   ", A[i][j]);
              printf("\n"); 
          }
      }

      // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

      int main(int argc, char *argv[])
      {
          float **A, **B, **C;  // matrices
          int d1, d2, d3;         // dimensions of matrices
          int i, j, k;          // loop variables


          double start, end;
          start = omp_get_wtime();

          /* print user instruction */
          if (argc != 4)
          {
              printf ("Matrix multiplication: C = A x B\n");
              printf ("Usage: %s <NumRowA>; <NumColA> <NumColB>\n",argv[0]); 
               return 0;
           }

           /* read user input */
           d1 = atoi(argv[1]);      // rows of A and C
           d2 = atoi(argv[2]);     // cols of A and rows of B
           d3 = atoi(argv[3]);     // cols of B and C

           printf("Matrix sizes C[%d][%d] = A[%d][%d] x B[%d][%d]\n", 
           d1, d3, d1, d2, d2, d3);

           /* prepare matrices */
           A = alloc_mat(d1, d2);
           init_mat(A, d1, d2); 
           B = alloc_mat(d2, d3);
           init_mat(B, d2, d3);
           C = alloc_mat(d1, d3);   // no initialisation of C, 
       //because it gets filled by matmult

           /* serial version of matmult */
           printf("Perform matrix multiplication...\n");



           int sum;
           //#pragma omp parallel
           //{
               #pragma omp parallel for collapse(3) schedule(guided)
               for (i = 0; i < d1; i++)
                   for (j = 0; j < d3; j++)
                       for (k = 0; k < d2; k++){
                       C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j];
                       }
           //}


           end = omp_get_wtime();


           /* test output */
           print_mat(A, d1, d2, "A"); 
           print_mat(B, d2, d3, "B"); 
           print_mat(C, d1, d3, "C"); 

           printf("This task took %f seconds\n", end-start);
           printf ("\nDone.\n");

           return 0;
       }
```

Comment: you probably shouldn't time all of your IO and initialization stuff. Try timing just the nested for loops and see if you get the same results.

Comment: if you still get worse performance with the parallel version, you should probably find somebody more skilled than I to help. But my first instinct is that the inner loop is not very well-suited to running in parallel. Since you're repeatedly performing operations on the same variable, so only one thread can update `c[i][j]` at a time. You might try parallelizing only the outer two loops.

Comment: `#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) private (k)`
        `for (i = 0; i < d1; i++)`
            `for (j = 0; j < d3; j++){`
                `for (k = 0; k < d2; k++){`
                `C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j];`
                `}`
            `}` I tried this but it didn't work either... @genisage

Comment: and if i only time the loop the serial version is alomost twice as fast.

Comment: my only other idea is that the matrices you're using might be small enough that the overhead from creating a team outweighs the benefits.

Comment: Try allocating your array in one block, and use x + y * width to find the index. It has better cache performance.

Comment: @NeilKirk If you look at his `alloc_mat` function, A2 is actually allocated all in one block, but he uses a separate array of pointers to the beginning of each row so he can use the A[][] syntax. I agree its unnecessary, though

Comment: @user3288829 That is very slow. In that case he can use operator overloading if he really wants to use that syntax.

Answer (score 2):

As @genisage suggested in the comments, the size of matrix is likely small enough that the overhead of initializing the additional threads is greater than the time savings achieved by computing the matrix multiplication in parallel. Consider the following plot, however, with data that I obtained by running your code with and without OpenMP. [image: Serial vs. Parallel Matrix Multiplication comparison]

I used square matrices ranging from n=10 to n=1000. Notice how somewhere between n=50 and n=100 the parallel version becomes faster.

There are other issues to consider, however, when trying to write fast matrix multiplication, which mostly have to do with using the cache effectively. First, you allocate your entire matrix contiguously (which is good), but still use two pointer redirections to access the data, which is unnecessary. Also, your matrices are stored in row major format, which means you are accessing the data in A and C contiguously, but not in B. Instead of explicitly storing B and multiplying a row of A with a column of B, you would get a faster multiplication by storing B transposed and multiplying a row of A elementwise with a row of B transpose.

This is an optimization focused only on A*B, however, and there may be other places in your code where storing B is better than B transpose, in which case often doing [matrix multiplication by blocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication) can lead to better cache utilization